# Publish UWP game to Xbox through the Xbox Live Creators Program

Tags: uwp, publish, xbox-live

The game that I want to publish, its' first iteration will mostly be about local multiplayer. When I go to publish the game to the Xbox store I get the following error:

```
Because you’ve selected the Games category for this app, you must complete 
the concept approval process before you can publish a submission targeting 
the Xbox device family.
```

I have been approved to be apart of the Xbox Live Creators program. On the creators site it talks about four steps you must follow. However, these steps don't mention the simplified concept approval process. Does anyone know how to get your UWP game through the concept approval process for the Creators program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are hitting on one of the documented limitations of the Insider Program - namely, that you cannot publish your game with the Xbox Live integrations until the summer.

Once we open up the program outside of the Insider Program, you can publish the game without concept approval or by being part of ID@Xbox.

For now, you can integrate Xbox Live into your game for both PC and Xbox One - sideloading the game onto those devices - within your developer sandbox.

If you need to publish your game before we allow publishing for Xbox Live Creators, you can disable the logic in your code and disable the setting in the Dev Center. That will allow you to publish to PC (although not Xbox).

You can ask Xbox Live related non-programming questions here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=xboxlivedev

Comment: I got this error just now, and it is already end of October. Are we missing something? I have MSFT friend who was able to publish by posting to App category on Xbox. But its kinda stupid, and requires me to have a separate submission to Games category for all other non-Xbox UWP platforms.

Comment: We have launched the Creators Program on Xbox which enables games to ship on Xbox.  You can ship a Creators game on PC as well.  More info can be found here: https://www.xbox.com/en-us/developers/creators-program

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was missing:
First, I had to enable [Xbox Live Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/get-started-with-creators/create-and-test-a-new-creators-title#enable-xbox-live-services) for the title.

Second, I had to create xboxservices.config as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/get-started-with-creators/develop-creators-title-with-visual-studio)